# Django - How to setup dynamic templating within django

Tags: django, templates, dynamic

So I am having this major issue regarding the templating setup. I have a model that is created and attaches html, JS, and CSS files on upload to a corresponding folder with the model name. The user is able to upload these files (HTML,CSS,JS), and I need to be able to access the HTML file within this weird location.

/template/app/app.html (the location where the view leads, which idc about)
/media/uploads/modelName1/base.html  ( I want to dynamically link each view with their corresponding model folder )

/media/uploads/modelName1/style.css

/media/uploads/modelName1/base.js

for the view I made it so the HTML file of the model is passed within the template and then I can use {% include %} but obv that can't work b.c the HTML included isn't even part of the template. If you have any suggestions on how to approach this problem, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you try add your own template dirs in settings.py?

Comment: I haven’t because I assumed I would have to keep adding new dirs for each new model. But I’ll give it a shot.

Comment: It didn't work, but I am able to embed the html file through an Iframe. I didn't have to override any template settings for that, I will be moving forward with this approach till I find a more efficient approach. The iframe must be able to communicate with the backend, and since it's within the same domain, I think it might be possible.